# Microsoft Access Question

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I do not know VB that well. I can figure out most things. I was wondering if anyone can tell me what this line of code means

```
Option Compare Database
```

Comment: Has it ever occured to you to highlight the word "COMPARE" and hit the F1 key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "In this module, compare strings using rules that are defined in the database."

Alternatives are `Option Compare Text` (case-insensitive compare) and `Option Compare Binary` (case-sensitive).

Had you used Google, you would immediately have found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98227/en-us) that explains everything.

Comment: I use Google a lot but tons of sites are blocked (filtered). Many of them are classified as shopping, recreation, unknown. So doing any work is hard especially without the necessary resources. Fortunately, StackOverflow is allowed.

Comment: It should also be noted that while the other Option Compare variants (Text and Binary) are supported in stand-alone VB code, Option Compare Database is only applicable to VB modules used within Microsoft Access.

Comment: @Cocoa Dev `Option Compare` is explained in Access' Help system.  That should be especially valuable for you since your internet searching is so restricted.

Comment: To repeat @Hansup, the F1 key is your friend.

Comment: To be slightly more accurate, it only applies in VBA modules.  VBA is not VB in the most meaningful sense.

Comment: VBA is a SUPERSET of VB, actually.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton In which sense? Explain please.

Comment: VBA adds lots of functionality specific to the host applications while using the core VB6 DLL.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton This functionality is exposed in form of COM objects by the hosting application. The fact that VBA uses it does not mean these features belong to the language. You can use the Excel object model from C++, and that doesn't make this particular piece of C++ a superset of "regular" C++.

Comment: Michael Kaplan has called VBA a superset of VB, and he knows way more than me. You may not recognize the name, so his authority may mean nothing to you. In a little googling I can't find his explanation on this, so will leave it at that.